# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060052

Tags: android

I have implemented my splash activity with this approach https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154 it works on my Android 7.0 but it crashes on Android 4.4.4 and 4.1.1 I have checked many threads on stackoverflow that didn't work for me.

I have this splash.xml in `drawable` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/waze_blue_bg" />
    <item android:top="-120dip">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ill_intro_logo"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

SplashActivity.kt

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
            startActivity(Intent(this, TutorialPagerActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH)

    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.williams.travelshare/com.williams.travelshare.splash.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060052
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060052
 at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
 at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:85)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:206)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
 at com.williams.travelshare.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:14)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 07-13 10:44:24.791 345-347/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 716352 bytes, got 16192
```

Comment: add your SplashActivity xml

Comment: @OussemaAroua I don't have any xml of it.

Comment: Are you have the image in drawable folder ill_intro_logo

Comment: Are you using kotlin

Comment: @Raj Yes I have image in different drawables. I have in hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. Weird is it works on Android 7.0

Comment: Did u try clean and rebuild your project

Comment: names of drawable folders

Comment: @SunilP Yes I did it multiple times, but no luck

Comment: @Williams Your drawable folder names and your image type(jpg or png)

Comment: Check minimum and maximum API level in build.gradle file.

Comment: @Raj see here http://imgur.com/a/H8Moo

Comment: @SunilP `minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26`

Comment: make minSdkVersion 15  and check

Comment: and also go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296988/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f040019

Comment: @SunilP this is not my case, I don't have a layout file for my splash. If you see this https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154 that can make you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: lookup the id mentioned in your `R` class. having the same issue right now. for me it is a drawable from the support libary that i'm not even using. it is `R.drawable.abc_vector_test`. For me it looks like it tries to load a svg drawable but 4.x this not supported... not sure why it does this yet. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bug on android side. I fixed it by disabling `android.enableAapt2` in `gradle.properties`

> android.enableAapt2=false

You can check it here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63642784

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</item>
```

use:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_penguin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
```