# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on startup, only in api 23 and below

Tags: android

I have been testing my apps primarily on API 26 and 27, big mistake as I am learning now. The app ran crash free on startup in API 24, 25, 26, and 27. Google's pre-launch report then brought a crash to my attention on API 23 and bellow. The log has listings about the menu, so I debugged it and found out that it crashes when I call

> MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
>
> inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);

Here is the error that is returned after that:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06006b
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:125)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:210)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:187)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:196)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:505)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1164)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:291)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1051)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1078)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1419)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1657)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the menu file I am inflating:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sms"
        android:orderInCategory="96"
        android:icon="@drawable/send_text"
        android:title="@string/send_sms"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_undo"
        android:orderInCategory="97"
        android:icon="@drawable/undo"
        android:title="@string/undo"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_switch_courts"
        android:orderInCategory="98"
        android:icon="@drawable/reverse"
        android:title="@string/change_courts"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reset"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        android:title="@string/reset" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check if you have added drawable image in this folder 
 : \app\src\main\res\drawable-21 ,
 move it to
 \app\src\main\res\drawable

Comment: I had nothing in drawable-21, but I moved everything out of drawable-v24 and that fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have created any resource under -v21 (or similar) folders. Move to base folder.

Refer: [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296988/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f040019)

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: The resources were stored in -v24, moving them to the base directory fixed the problem, thank you

Comment: Also moving fixed the problem